# Spring hibernate One to Many not showing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I am trying to build a web app that has two kinds of objects: books and reviews (where a book can have multiple reviews).

I can see the list of books, but when I enter the book page I can see the title and other attributes of the book but the attributes of the reviews will not show and I do not know why. I can only see an empty table with a single row with empty values.

I think that it doesn't recognise the object because there are three entries in the review table so if it would have recognised the table then the table have had three rows.

**Book.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

    private int bookId;
    private int bookRating;
    private String bookCategory;
    private String bookAuthor;
    private String bookTitle;

    @Transient
    private Set<Review> review;

    @Transient  
    private List<String> reviews;

    public Book() {}

    public Book(String title) {
        this.bookTitle = title;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "BOOKID")
    public int getBookid() {
        return bookId;
    }

    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="r_bookid")
    public Set<Review> getReviews() {
        return review;
    }

    public void setReviews(Set<Review> reviews) {
        this.review = review;
    }
}
```

**Review.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "REVIEW")
public class Review {

private int id;
private Date r_date;
private String r_author;
private String r_text;
private int r_rating;
@Transient
private Set<Review> review;
private Book book;
private int r_bookid;

public Review(String author, String text, Date date, int rating, int bookid, Book book) {   
    super();
    this.r_author = author;
    this.r_text = text;
    this.r_date = date;
    this.r_rating = rating;
    this.r_bookid = bookid;
    this.book= book;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Review> getReviews() {
    return review;
}
```

**BookDAOImpl.java**

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public Set<Review> getReviews() {
  Set<Review> listReview = (Set<Review>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(Review.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
  return listReview;
}
```

**Controller.java**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewBook(HttpServletRequest request) {
  int bookId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
  Book book = bookDao.get(bookId);
  Set<Review> review = book.getReviews();
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("viewBook");
  model.addObject("book", book);
  model.addObject("review", review);      
  return model;  
 }
```

**viewBook.jsp**

```jsp
<h1>Carte: ${book.bookTitle}</h1>
<h2>Autor: ${book.bookAuthor}</h2>

<c:forEach var="rev" items="${review}" varStatus="status">
<tr>
  <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
  <td>${rev.r_author}</td>
  <td>${rev.r_text}</td>
  <td>${rev.r_date}</td>
  <td>${rev.r_rating}</td> 
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**Database tables**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE test;

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `bookId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookTitle` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `bookAuthor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `bookCategory` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `bookRating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookId`)
);

CREATE TABLE `review` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `r_author` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `r_text` varchar(205) NOT NULL,
  `r_rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `r_date` date NOT NULL,
  `r_bookid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `r_bookid_idx` (`r_bookid`),
  CONSTRAINT `r_bookid` FOREIGN KEY (`r_bookid`) REFERENCES `book` (`bookId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: @Transient
private Set<Review> review. Remove this code from Review class. and remove Transient from annotation from Book Class

Comment: I removed the annotation from both class and removed the Set<review> method from Review class but now i get the following error :     Could not determine type for: com.bookr.app.model.Book, at table: REVIEW, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(book)]

Comment: Fixed some phrasing, syntax highlighting, and removed please/thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Transient annotation. This annotation specifies do not persist the annotated field.

Comment: Is there data in the database. Because there couldn't be any before.

Comment: Yes, i have data inserted, i was making a mistake that's why nothing changed,  now i get the following error : Could not determine type for: com.bookr.app.model.Book, at table: REVIEW, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(book)].  I think that has something to do with the private Book book; declaration from Review class but i am not sure

Comment: This is the entire error message: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.bookr.app.config.ApplicationContextConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.bookr.app.config.ApplicationContextConfig.getSessionFactory(javax.sql.DataSource)] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.bookr.app.model.Book, at table: REVIEW, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(book)]

Comment: Please remove that JoinColumn stuff as long as your not 100% sure you need it. I think I need to write a JPA how to blog entry.

Comment: now my code looks like this: `@OneToMany
 public Set<Review> getReviews() {
  return review;
 }`   in Book.java and  `@ManyToOne
 public Book getBook() {
  return book;
 }` in Review.java and i get the error: `Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: REVIEW, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(reviews)]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with the mapping itself.

Please, take a look at this [blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation). I think it may help you.

Comment: I followed the guide and i got this error: R_BOOKID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"). After i added insertable=false and updatable=false in the @Column annotation for the r_bookid i get: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

Comment: are you using spring mvc with hibernate or not ? i think you are hitting url but that req is not mapped with any servlet method

Comment: yes, i am using, i can upload the entire project if you think it's helpful, or i can add more of the code

Comment: `public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
         
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}`